# In Android :: When setContentView() is replaced with new layout while in runtime which method is called

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Hi I am new to android programming.
Here my problem is... 
I designed 2 layouts.

1) **R.layout.main**: it consists one TextField,one EditText and one Button

2) **R.layout.window**: it holds 5 buttons

here at first,R.layout.main is displayed.By default R.layout.main is calling so when i press the button of that main layout it needs to forward to r.layout.window.
Forwarding process is ok..

BUT WHEN I MAKE CALL LIKE 
`BUTTON button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);// b1 is at R.layout.window`

i am getting an exception.. SO CAN I KNOW WHICH METHOD WILL BE CALLED WHEN setContentView() IS CALLED and FROM ONCREATE(),IS IT POSSIBLE TO CALL MULTIPLE LAYOUTS R.id.namess..

waiting for reply

Comment: What Exception you got? give a logcat here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class UI extends Activity {
    LayoutInflater factory 
    View layout1;
    View layout2;    
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
 .....
 .....

 factory =getLayoutInflater();
 layout1 =  factory.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
 layout2 =  factory.inflate(R.layout.window, null);
.....
..... 
   }
}



//access R.id.b1 in R.layout.window;
```

try this

```
Button button=(Button)layout2.findViewById(R.id.b1);
```

if you set the content view to R.layout.main like this `setContentView(R.layout.main);` then
you can  access widgets in the `R.layout.main` by  `findViewById()`  only like this

```
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

where `R.id.button1` inside `R.layout.main` then when you finish with `R.layout.main`  set the content view of window layout and then access the widgets inside it

```
setContentView(R.layout.window);

//now you can access elements in window layout using findViewById
Button b2  =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
```

hope you understand

Comment: still getting Nullpointer exception at Button button=(Button)layout2.findViewById(R.id.b1);

Comment: hi nammari ji, check this code snippet and reply public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     View layout1 = findViewById(R.layout.main);
     View layout2 = findViewById(R.layout.window);setContentView(R.layout.main);Button press=(Button)findViewById(R.id.press);
        Button button=(Button)layout2.findViewById(R.id.b1); press.setOnClickListener(button_listener);}  OnClickListener button_listener=new OnClickListener() {
  
  public void onClick(View v) {
 setContentView(R.layout.window);}};   so with this code i am getting nullpoi exe

Comment: LOGCAT IS AS FOLLOWS .................................................      12-05 14:31:43.862: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(217):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

Comment: HI Nammari ji, thanks for responses and now i got FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION in logcat

Comment: Nammari ji check my files i am sending